# Regular expression for getting values inside brackets

Tags: java, regex

Below are the String values I want to separate the inside brackets value

```
US Records (100)
Foreign Records (243)
```

In the string above I want to separate the counts and store into another string
100, 243 using regular expression.

Comment: While you wait for someone else to write your code for you, maybe you could read up on this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 3):

This code schold give you the result:

```
String s = new String("US Records (100)");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+)\\)");

Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

m.find();

System.out.println(m.group(1));
```